# How to change BarChart labels font?

Tags: formatting, labeling, charts

The question seems trivial, but no sign of such thing in reference. Also `TicksStyle` does not work for labels.

Thanks,
Regards

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Something like this?

```
BarChart[{{1, 2, 3}, {1, 3, 2}, {5, 2}}, 
 ChartLabels -> {"a", "b", "c"}, 
 BaseStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Zapfino", FontSize -> 16]]
```

[image: zapfino]

At first glance, the online documentation for `BarChart` doesn't describe any useful font options, but when you see the phrase *"BarChart has the same options as Graphics with the following additions and changes"*, you realise that you can try the more general options that work for most 2D graphical output in *Mathematica*. So, although `BaseStyle` isn't shown in that list (since presumably there are no additions or changes specifically for `BarChart`), it works OK here.

In the same way, you can use `Background` to place a colored background behind a chart. It's not specifically listed in the documentation for `BarChart`, but once you know that `Graphics` options also apply, it's worth a try. Eventually, you'll be able to remember all the options, or you'll get there by trial and error. In my experience, the documentation *probably* contains the information you want, but it's not always on the first page you look at.

```
BarChart[{{1, 2, 3}, {1, 3, 2}},
 ChartLabels -> {"a", "b", "c"}, 
 ChartStyle -> "FruitPunchColors",
 BaseStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Zapfino", FontSize -> 12],
 Background -> LightGray]
```

[image: another graphic]

Comment: @chris better than Comic Sans at least :)

Comment: @cormullion - or Algerian!

Comment: @stevenvh Yes! There are very few fonts that end up having their own hate pages on the internet, and I discovered today that Algerian joins that elite group.

Answer (score 6):

For the specific task of styling BarChart labels I would use `Style` directly.

When using the `BaseStyle` option other elements are affected, potentially in undesirable ways, and some directives are not applied to the labels:

```
BarChart[{{1, 2, 3}, {1, 3, 2}, {5, 2}},
 ChartLabels -> {"a", "b", "c"},
 BaseStyle -> Directive[Red, FontFamily -> "Stencil Std", FontSize -> 16]
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

As you can see the axis lines are made red, which I did not desire, yet the A B C labels remain black.  The style I desired may be produced with a more targeted approach:

```
lblStyle = Style[#, 16, Red, FontFamily -> "Stencil Std"] &;

BarChart[{{1, 2, 3}, {1, 3, 2}, {5, 2}},
 ChartLabels -> lblStyle /@ {"a", "b", "c"}
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you wish to style the 1 through 5 labels as well that can be done independently with `LabelStyle`:

```
BarChart[{{1, 2, 3}, {1, 3, 2}, {5, 2}},
 ChartLabels -> lblStyle /@ {"a", "b", "c"},
 LabelStyle -> {22, Blue, Italic}
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]